# Vue slot loads async component before the slot v-if statement kicks in

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having a problem where an sync components JavaScript is loaded before it is actually shown.

Components that are imported with a `dynamic-import` are shown using `v-if` to load them when they are needed. When they are shown their JavaScript is loaded as well. But in the case of a `slot` the v-if does not prevent the component from already loading its generated chunk of JavaScript and appending it to the DOM.

Dropdown component:

```
<template>
    <li class="dropdown" :class="{ open: visible }">
        <div class="heading" @click.stop="toggle">
            <span>{{ heading }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="slot-content" v-if="visible">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

Usage of the component with the async `google-map` component in the slot:

```
<dropdown>
    <google-map>
        <map-marker :data="{{ $marker }}"></map-marker>
    </google-map>
</dropdown>
```

Even though the slot has a `v-if`, the components JavaScript is still being loaded. Weirdly enough neither the mounted or created are fired though. So it seems everything abides the proper rules except the async loading of the component.

Preferably I could use the slot with a `v-if` and not trigger the loading of the generated chunk for this `async` component.

Obviously it is not such a big problem if it loads asynchronously but even HTTP2 has its limits when it comes down to requests. I would rather load it when needed.

Comment: Try to use `v-cloak` which will hide the HTML with CSS until the component is fully loaded.

Comment: `v-cloak` simply applies a `dislay: none` which does nothing to stop the aync generated JavaScript from still being loaded. Plus I already tried messing around with it, to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the doc about Compilation Scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope)

> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope;
> everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope.

That's why your problem occurs. There's nothing in the parent template that indicates that the component shouldn't be rendered.

It can be solved by using **[Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)**

simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/8kmLpj75/6/

In the example, just by adding `<template slot-scope="{}">` to the async component, it forces the async component to wait until the slot's parent scope becomes available. (I honestly don't know its exact inner working either).

In your case, simply adding `<template slot-scope="{}">` should solve the problem as well

```
<dropdown>
    <template slot-scope="{}">
        <google-map>
            <map-marker :data="{{ $marker }}"></map-marker>
        </google-map>
    </template>
</dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work I would love some more explanation about the workings of this though. But it does the job for now. thanks!

Comment: I am also surprised that this works, would love some explanation too haha